# until item does not exists in array do in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have below part of the code

```
jmsPort=61015
jmsPorts=(61018 61016 61017)

until [ $jmsPorts -ne $jmsPort ]; do    
    jmsPort=$(expr $jmsPort + 1)
done
```

The iteration of the loop is only once in this case, how can use do this 
until the jmsPorts array does not contain the jmsPort do (jmsPort + 1)

**the goal that I want to achieve is**

If the jmsPort matches an element in the array: 
It should do + 1 to the jmsPort until the jmsPort does not match an element in the jmsPorts array

If the jmsPort is not in the array:
it should choose the jmsPort

I have done this using PowerShell but can't do it in Bash. 
the syntax in PowerShell is

```
$jmsPort = 61016
$jmsPorts = @(61018, 61016, 61017)

do
{
    $jmsPort = $jmsPort + 1
} 
until ($jmsPorts -notcontains $jmsPort )
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this script?

Comment: The powershell information is unnecessary. You may delete that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that

```
jmsPorts=() # jmsPorts is an array
```

To update the array, initially(before the edit) you've put

```
jmsPorts+=$(echo $i | grep -oP '\d+') # Wrong
```

It should've been

```
jmsPorts+=( "$(echo $i | grep -oP '\d+')" ) #mind the outer brackets.
```

Now to check if `jmsPort` doesn't match any element in `jmsPorts` array do

```
validator(){
flag=0 # Assuming the element is not present
for i in "${jmsPorts[@]}"
do
 if [ "$1" -eq "$i" ]
 then
  flag=1 # Element is present
 fi
done
}
while validator "$jmsPort" && [ "$flag" -eq 1 ]
do
((jmsPort++))
done

echo "Port Chosen : $jmsPort"  
# This port doesn't match any value in the array.
```

---

<sup>**Warning :** Ports 1-65535 are available, and ports in range 1-1023 are the privileged ones. On more complicated scenatios an extra check `[ $jmsPort -lt 65535 ]` might be necessary.</sup>

Comment: Great answer! Deserved an ^, had to take down mine, as it didn't work for all use cases.

Comment: it is exiting the script .. it is not working . there is something wrong